# How to make changes are not visible in userside using wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to edit contents of the existing page in wordpress.It is a live site so user side should not be changed
untill i want to publish that after all changes made to that page.Is there any plugin or what 
i have to do for this.
Anyone please help me.

Comment: Don't click publish then, just make your edits and click the Preview Changes button (normally above the blue Update button).

Answer (score 0):

It depends what sort of changes. As noted above if you're channing post contents if will be enough not to publish them, but I guess you already now that.
However if you want to change appearance of the site then caching plugin might help. E.g. with w3 total cache you can do any change to template/css/php and so on and only logged in users will see changes (any non logged in user will get cached version of the page until you clean cache or cache expires). 
If you have also users which are logging in into your wordpress, then I'm not aware of already made plugin that have such functionality - you probably would have to  create development version of your site and test changes there.

Answer (score 0):

For content - agree with previous answers.

But if you are changing the theme and want some changes to be visible only for you (admin) then you can use `is_admin()` function to print out different content for admin (new one) and different for other users (old one).

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin